# Add Buttons after create a JqueryUI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add buttons after create a jquery UI dialog.But the following code not working.

My requirement is the button content should be passed dynamically in the form of JSON. So I'm creating the jquery UI dialog and adding the button content to it.

A sample JSON structure given below.

```
 "buttons": [{
                        "text": "button1",
                        "functionname": "test12",
                        "fncparam": { "param1": "testparam1", "param2": "1273576235" }
}]

 function dialog_box(dynDiv, rootTemplate) {
            var dialog_buttons = rootTemplate.buttons;
            var dialog = $("#" + dynDiv.id).dialog({
                hide: "explode",
                title: rootTemplate.etype,
                buttons: {},
                text: rootTemplate.text,
                resizable: true,
                minWidth: 200,
                minHeight: 150,
                close: function() {
                    $(dialog).dialog('destroy').remove();
                }
            });

            $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons',
          [
                { text: 'New Button 01', click: function(ev, ui) { alert('New Button 01'); } }
                , { text: 'New Button 02', click: function(ev, ui) { alert('New Button 02'); } }

          ]);


        }
```

what's wrong in this? 
Any other alternatives to add buttons after create Jquery UI dialog?

Answer (score 0):

make button like this way

```
$("#" + dynDiv.id).dialog({
                hide: "explode",
                title: rootTemplate.etype,
                buttons: {},
                text: rootTemplate.text,
                resizable: true,
                minWidth: 200,
                minHeight: 150,
        buttons: [ 
        { text: "Close", 
        click: function() {
         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         } 
    } ] 
    });
```

Comment: My button content is not static. I need to pass this as dynamic in the form of JSON. That's why Im adding after creating the dialog.    "buttons": [{
                        "text": "button1",
                        "functionname": "test12",
                        "fncparam": { "param1": "testparam1", "param2": "1273576235" }
}]

Comment: How i can add the function name here? for eg: function name is test12 and params are "param1": "testparam1", "param2": "1273576235"

Comment: $("#" + dynDiv.id) is same like $('#dialog') ?

Comment: yes.$("#" + dynDiv.id)is the div id to which i need to append the jquery UI dialog.

Comment: then use  $(("#" + dynDiv.id).dialog('option', 'buttons',

Comment: How i can add function names and params here?

Comment: { buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() {//add function names and params } } ] } i think by this way you add i didn't find any way to add like this way which you want